# How can I run the SQL like "SELECT * from table where columnA = columnB;" in Parse API?

Tags: sql, rest, parse-platform

In Parse, I am using REST API to retrieve some results from a table.
I would like to select a row where the value of one column is equal to another column. i.e. I would like to send the SQL like

```
SELECT * from table where columnA = columnB;
```

there's a document here  ( http://parse.com/docs/rest/guide )  and it shows how to send the query like

```
SELECT * from table where columnA = 'some value';
```

but it doesn't say how to send what I want to. I have tried a couple of ways which I thought would do but never succeded.

Comment: Your query looks correct for your stated purpose.

Comment: if your table is called table and your columns are actually called columnA and columnB then this is a correct query, but you might want to put bracketss around your table name like so: [table] because table is a reserved word

Comment: Is this part of a larger query? are you getting an error?